# How to extract table data from website with dynamically content with requests and BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrapy

I'm having some problems extracting the table from this page: [www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/aapl/dividend-history](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/aapl/dividend-history)

My code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/aapl/dividend-history", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'dividend-history__table'})
table_body = table.find('tbody', attrs={'class': 'dividend-history__table-body'})
data = []
rows = table_body.find('tr', attrs={'class': 'dividend-history__row dividend-history__row--data'})
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values
```

They have the table in an iframe. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - it's the first time I use BeautifulSoup - I normally use requests + xPath for this sort of a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What happens?

1. Table is not in an iframe as you guess.
2. Table data is generated dynamically so you could not grab it, with your approach
3. Everything would work fine till this lines,  if content would be static.

---

Take a look `find()` only get the first occurrence of your filter - only one `<tr>` instead you should use `find_all()`

`rows = table_body.find('tr', attrs={'class': 'dividend-history__row dividend-history__row--data'})`

You try to loop a non iterable:

```
for row in rows:
```

Same thing with `find()` again:

```
cols = row.find('td')
```

And again iterating an non iterable:

```
cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
```

### What about an alternativ?

There are different approaches to scrape data from websites and you often came to limits with `requests` if they deal with dynamically data.

**How about using websites api?**

With requests and pandas it could be so simple:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/AAPL/dividends?assetclass=stocks"
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['data']['dividends']['rows'])
df
```

**Output**

```
exOrEffDate type    amount  declarationDate recordDate  paymentDate

11/06/2020  CASH    $0.205  10/29/2020  11/09/2020  11/12/2020
08/07/2020  CASH    $0.82   07/30/2020  08/10/2020  08/13/2020
05/08/2020  CASH    $0.82   04/30/2020  05/11/2020  05/14/2020
02/07/2020  CASH    $0.77   01/28/2020  02/10/2020  02/13/2020
11/07/2019  CASH    $0.77   10/30/2019  11/11/2019  11/14/2019
```